# Audit first post question

Tags: support, comment, review-audit

I was reviewing through the “first posts” on an iPad when I come up across a question about conjugates. Because it was an audit, it did not show any comments... etc. I decided to first comment on it, explaining what a conjugate is and asking for clarification on why the poster said that 5$\pm\sqrt{2}$ was not a conjugate and then answer the question after upvoting. After finishing my comment, I click return, and then boom it said I failed the audit.

What exactly happenned? Why did I fail?

Here’s the link if any of you can see/access it: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1270918

Comment: Apparently you should have chosen "No Action needed". Why the system objects to comments in such review audits is beyond me.

Comment: See also: [Try to comment: Fail review audit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11307).

Comment: next time click to the actual question so you can see the answers potentially to see if it's actually new ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee ok got it!